# multiple arrow shapes on submenu using :after css

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to fix a bug that I have when I click the an element with the active state. I am using this code to draw a arrow like shape to my menu on the active buttons:

```css
.bookmarks ul li:active::after
 {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(30, 64, 86, 0);
    border-left-color: #1e4056;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```

but when I click some of the submenu links I get this result:

[image]

with multiple arrows showing. I've tried the > in couple of places, like .bookmarks ul > li:active::after and nothing worked so far. Any Ideas?

```css
.bookmarks ul > li:active::after
 {
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: rgba(30, 64, 86, 0);
    border-left-color: #1e4056;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
}


This is my html structure, is a ul with li's, and another two ul submenus.
```

```html
<div class="product" id="affix-nav"> 
        <ul class="nav top-menu" id="affix-ul">
          <li class="link1">
              <a href="#"">
              Link 1
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="link2">
            <a href="#">
              Link 2
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="link3">
            <a href="#">
              Link 3
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="link4">
            <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
              <a href="#" class="left-side">
                <span>Link 4</span>
              </a>  
              <a href="#" class="arrow-up right-side" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuOne">
                <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                </i>
              </a> 
            </div>
            <ul id="hiddenMenuOne" class="collapse first-tree">
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sub link 1</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sub link 2</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sub link 3</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sub link 4</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sub link 5</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Sub link 6</a>
              </li>
              <li class="clearfix double-btn">
                  <div class="dbl-link-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link left-link left-side">
                    Third Level Link 1
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="right-side arrow-up" aria-hidden="true" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hiddenMenuTwo">
                      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down">
                      </i>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                <ul id="hiddenMenuTwo" class="collapse second-tree">
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level Link 1</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level Link 2</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a href="#">Third Level Link 3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>   
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a full demo, or include the rest of the CSS/JQuery - it would help debug

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a possible solution to your problem, but using :active on the link instead of the li would solve the problem. When the li is active, the parent(s) up the hierarchy are also considered active. I don't know how you can work around that. You can look at this as example: http://codepen.io/andreasmcdermott/pen/qRYJWJ The green arrow is added for each parent as well. The blue arrow is only added to specific link. **edit** It is worth mentioning that from accessibility viewpoint the link is better as well since that will be active when tabbed to.

Comment: Hey andreas, I did try that implementation, but I am still having the issue. I even try to play around with :not but no luck so far. I will keep at it.

Comment: @ovokuro the code base is pretty big, that's why I didn't add it here.

Comment: Is this live anywhere or can you reproduce the error in snippet? I don't think anyone can help you otherwise.